# implode with while regrouping php

Tags: php

when i am trying to while an implode it's regroup all result in the last result 
what i'm trying to do is regroup the tag of on topic in here case
this is the code

```
//$fetch = select from table;

while ( $p = mysql_fetch_array($fetch) ) {
$skills = explode(',',$p[skills]);
foreach($skills as $skls){
$skills2[] = $skls;
}
$skills3 = implode(' ',$skills2);
```

but all the result while regroupe in the final result
ex:

```
1 | php,c++,c
2 | perl,c#
3 | photoshop,web_support

if id number 1 appears php,c++,c
but in number 2 appears php,c++,c,perl,c#
and number 3 appears php,c++,c,perl,c#,photoshop,web_support
```

Comment: It's very hard to read your question. I guess you have an error when accessing the array index in the explode line $p[skills] should probably be $p['skills']

Comment: first i'm sorry about my english because i'm not good in it 
second the problems is'nt there the code work normaly but the problem is in the last result it's regroup all the result and get it in finaly please red the second notice you will understand what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the values for each iteration of the outer loop, then you need to reset your variable each time.

Otherwise the $skills2[] will just keep adding new indexes to the $skills2 array.

Try something like:

```
while ( $p = mysql_fetch_array($fetch) ) { 
    $skills = explode(',',$p[skills]); 
    $skills2 = array(); // initialise $skills2 as an empty array
    foreach($skills as $skls){ 
        $skills2[] = $skls; 
    } 
    $skills3 = implode(' ',$skills2);
    //var_dump($skills3);
}
```